# Wrong insert in procedure MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert, addition, procedure

wrong INSERT in Procedure . This insert add all column without **UserId**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CreateTable $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `CreateTable`
(
    md5 VARCHAR(255),table_name VARCHAR(255),CommentsId INT(11),
    Parent VARCHAR(100), Content TEXT,UserId INT(11), Title VARCHAR(255), 
    Nick VARCHAR(20), IdLength INT(11), suffix INT(11)
)
BEGIN



DECLARE full_table_name varchar(255);

SET @SQL=CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(\'X\') INTO @COUNTER FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ',
            'WHERE TABLE_NAME like \'', table_name, '%\'');

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    SET full_table_name= table_name;


    SET @SQL=CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', full_table_name, ' LIKE CommentsPattern');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


SET @SQL=CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', full_table_name,'(md5,UserId, Parent, Content, CommentsId, Title, Nick,IdLength,suffix)',
        'values(',UserId,',"',md5, '",', Parent, ',"', Content, '",',CommentsId,',"',Title,'","',Nick,'",', IdLength, ',',suffix, ')');
    prepare stmt from @sql;
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt;

END
```

I want add this values:

```
call CreateTable('dcf57shasdsd5723m','dcf',2,60201,'My article is',444,'New Title','Ethan',1,2);
```

Where:

1. **md5** - dfc7shgsnsty3475723m
2. **table_name** - dfc
3. **UserId** - 444
4. **Title** - New Title
5. **Nick** - Ethan
6. **CommentsId** - 2
7. **Parent** - 60201
8. **IdLength** - 1
9. **suffix** - 2
10. **Content** -  My article is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the INSERT INTO you declare the columns in the order: md5, UserId, Parent,...
However, in the values the md5 and UserId values are switched: ',UserId,',"',md5, '",', Parent